# Como trabalhar com o GIT corretamente?

Tags: git

Estou iniciando um projeto em equipe e minha dúvida é se a ordem que eu estou seguindo é a correta ao trabalhar com o `GIT`.

1. Eu executo git pull origin master `//Aqui baixo os arquivos mais recentes do projeto`
2. Faço todas as alterações em uma issue.
3. Executo git checkout -b fix/issue_1
4. Depois executo o git status.
5. Em seguida executo git add .
6. Depois de tudo enviado, executo o git commit "issue teste"
7. E por final git push origin fix/issue_1

Comment: Neste caso, suas alterações não estarão espelhadas no *branch* `master` e, se o *issue* ocorre no `master`, não estaria, de fato, resolvido. É isso mesmo que você deseja?

Comment: Isso, nesse exemplo não está sendo enviado ao branch master, a dúvida é se a ordem está correta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maneira correta é um pouco relativa, mas vou mostrar como vem dando certo com nossa equipe, talvez possa dar uma ideia para você.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os branches de **hotfix** são bem parecidos com os branches **releases** (branches que adicionam uma nova funcionalidade), pois também preparam uma nova versão para ser enviada à produção, mas ela não é planejada. A ideia deles é suprir a necessidade de agir imediatamente após algum problema na versão que está em produção. Quando um erro crítico acontece ele deve ser resolvido imediatamente, para isso, então, deve ser criado um branch de **hotfix** a partir do **master**.

A grande sacada desse branch, é que os membros da equipe podem continuar o desenvolvimento do projeto no **develop** (ou o nome do branch de desenvolvimento principal que você utiliza, vou usar develop aqui para ficar mais didático) normalmente enquanto outro desenvolvedor realiza rapidamente uma correção para um problema `crítico`.

**Criando um branch de hotfix**

Os branchs de **hotfix** são criados a partir do **master**. Por exemplo, digamos que a **versão 1.2** é a versão que está em produção e devido a um erro grave, está causando problemas. As alterações realizadas no branch **develop** ainda estão instáveis, não sendo elegíveis a um release para **produção**. Devemos então criar um branch **hotfix** para corrigir o problema.

```
$ git checkout -b hotfix-1.2.1 master
# Switched to a new branch "hotfix-1.2.1"
$ ./bump-version.sh 1.2.1
# Files modified successfully, version bumped to 1.2.1.
$ git commit -a -m "Bumped version number to 1.2.1"
# [hotfix-1.2.1 41e61bb] Bumped version number to 1.2.1
# 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

Não esqueça de alterar o número da versão depois de criar o branch. Então envie as alterações em um ou mais commits. (Caso utilize esse esquema de versionamento)

```
$ git commit -m "Fixed severe production problem"
# [hotfix-1.2.1 abbe5d6] Fixed severe production problem
# 5 files changed, 32 insertions(+), 17 deletions(-)
```

**Finalizando um branch de hotfix**

Quando finalizado, um **hotfix** precisa ser mergeado de volta aos branches **master** e **develop** e agora aplique as alterações de volta em seu branch **master**.

```
$ git checkout master
# Switched to branch 'master'
$ git merge --no-ff hotfix-1.2.1
# Merge made by recursive.
# (Summary of changes)
$ git tag -a 1.2.1
```

Agora, inclua o bugfix no develop também:

```
$ git checkout develop
# Switched to branch 'develop'
$ git merge --no-ff hotfix-1.2.1
# Merge made by recursive.
# (Summary of changes)
```

A única exceção à regra aqui é quando existe um branch **release** corrente, então o hotfix irá ser mergeado com esse branch e consequentemente também será mergeado no **develop** quando o release for finalizado. Caso o **develop** precise urgentemente desse bugfix e não pode esperar, você pode mergear o branch **release** no branch **develop** sem prejuízos .

E finalmente o **hotfix** pode ser removido:

```
$ git branch -d hotfix-1.2.1
# Deleted branch hotfix-1.2.1 (was abbe5d6).
```

Você pode encontrar todo o processo [aqui nesse artigo em português](https://medium.com/@luizcarvalho/modelo-de-ger%C3%AAncia-de-branchs-de-sucesso-para-git-54955f876c7)

Comment: Tentei enviar um commit com o comando `git -f origin master` e acabei perdendo todos os meus commits que havia feito num repositório e nele ficou aparecendo somente os dois últimos que havia feito recentemente. Teria alguma maneira para recuperá-los de volta ao repositório?